# Gravitating sigma models

Tags: gravity, research-level, specific-reference, supergravity, sigma-models

I am looking for a review or book on sigma models in (super)gravity theories, which arise from dimensional reduction.

Answer (score 4):

A nice place to start from (in the context of SUSY)

http://inspirehep.net/record/11988?ln=en